# SSH Tunnel for Python MySQLdb connection

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I tried creating a SSH tunnel using

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:22 <hostip>
```

Then running my python script to connect via localhost

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host'localhost', port=3306, user='bob', passwd='na', db='test')
```

However, I receive the following error

```
(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

How can I make sure I'm hitting the correct host and not just some problem with the bind?

Comment: You can also try `sshtunnel` recipe: https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel#example-3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try changing `"localhost"` to `"127.0.0.1"`, it should work as you expect. This behavior is detailed in the [manual](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html):

> UNIX sockets and named pipes don't
>   work over a network, so if you specify
>   a host other than localhost, TCP will
>   be used, and you can specify an odd
>   port if you need to (the default port
>   is 3306):
>
> `db=_mysql.connect(host="outhouse", port=3307, passwd="moonpie", db="thangs")`
>
> If you really had to, you could
>   connect to the local host with TCP by
>   specifying the full host name, or
>   **127.0.0.1**.

Answer (score 13):

Does mysqld run on port 22 on the remote? Call me ignorant but I think what you're trying to do is

```
ssh -n -N -f -L 3306:localhost:3306 remotehost
```

Then making MySQL connections on local machine will transparently get tunneled over to the target host.

Comment: Yes,  and you can test it if you have a telnet client available on the local host:  `telnet localhost 3306` should establish a connection and display a recognizable MySQL version number.

Comment: I think this answer is better than the chosen one, because the proposed way makes it possible to stay on your local machine instead of being remote.

Answer (score 3):

You can't specify `localhost` as the hostname, as this suggests that MySQLdb should try to use a UNIX socket. Use `127.0.0.1` for the host instead.

If you want to make sure the connection works, you can use the standard mysql client.