# Connecting through Python to a MySQL database hosted on a remote server with no direct access

Tags: python, mysql

I wish to connect to a database server through my local machine at work, but I do not have direct access to the database server (due to security reasons). The database server is accessible through another intermediary server which I can connect to.

I understand I can connect to the database if I run my script on the intermediary server, but is there any way through which I can connect to the database server directly through my local machine?

I am trying to do this in a Python script as I wish to read the data into a pandas dataframe (I can do this part once I can set up the connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SSH access to that intermediary server you can connect via an SSH tunnel. This post describes how to do that: [Enable Python to Connect to MySQL via SSH Tunnelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903411/enable-python-to-connect-to-mysql-via-ssh-tunnelling)

Comment: Thank you @dmitrybelyakov ! That post helped me and I was able to accomplish my goal.