# How to connect to MySQL over `TCP/IP` and `TCP/IP over ssh` from python code?

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I am able to connect to my database with sql workbench. But when I am trying to connect with python code, I am getting confused. I have found some similar codes on internet and stack over flow but I am not able to connect with code.

How can I connect to the DB with the following details? Using python code.

[image: mySQL workbench connection]

EDIT::
I also want to know how to connect to TCP/IP over ssh. details shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the Python code you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python-mysql driver

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  port="2121",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword"
)

print(mydb)
```

This [doc explains](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) it in details.

Connecting VIA SSH is descibed here - [Enable Python to Connect to MySQL via SSH Tunnelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903411/enable-python-to-connect-to-mysql-via-ssh-tunnelling)

Comment: its not working

Comment: @AshutoshYadav what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: The port (and maybe database) is missing. It should be something like: mysql.connect.connect(host="123.45.67.89", port=2121, username="my_user_name", password="...", database="su")

Comment: @AshutoshYadav yes.. Like mentioned above, include the port as well if needed. Also post the errors which will be useful.

Comment: Thanks @Nuno It worked. I have edited the question. I am also looking to connect to TCP/IP over ssh as shown in image. please look into it and help if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @AshutoshYadav I think this is what you are looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903411/enable-python-to-connect-to-mysql-via-ssh-tunnelling