# Python connect to ssh mysql server

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I'm writing a small python program locally as i don't have root access on the server. It basically does a lot of mysql queries using python MySQLdb module.

The thing is I cant use MySQLdb with the server, as the mysql server is hosted locally and I need to ssh into the server and then use mysql from there.

Is there any module available where I can connect to a mysql database via SSH.

At the moment I can connect to the mysql instance using SSH credentials (IP, User, Pass)

I also have the user/pass for the mysql instance and I'm pretty sure it runs on 127.0.0.1/localhost.

Comment: Use an SSH tunnel (-L parameter)! It's out of scope for SO, so try man or google. Hint: Use an other port than 3306 for the client end or most MySQL clients will try to use the UNIX socket automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on Python, I would use paramiko:

https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko

This seems to be one of the most widely used Python SSH libraries. There are some other StackOverflow questions that address how to do this.

- [How to open an SSH tunnel using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364355/how-to-open-an-ssh-tunnel-using-python)
- [SSH Tunnel for Python MySQLdb connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577555/ssh-tunnel-for-python-mysqldb-connection)

The main idea is to create a tunnel with paramiko and then connect to the localhost port through which you are tunneling traffic to the remote server using the Python library MySQLdb.